# React Router Help: component appears when I would expect it not to

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying a simple routing with React. My understanding is that with the below, the Navi component being routed should only appear in the root url and not appear in any other url, however this is not the case - no matter the url, the component always appears. Could someone explain what I am missing?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Home from "./Home";
import Navi from "./Navi";
import Welcome from "./Welcome";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { user: "kungpow" };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Router>
          <Navi user={this.state.user} />
          <Route exact link="/" Component={Navi} />
        </Router>

        <Home user={this.state.user} />
        <Welcome user={this.state.user} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are missing `path` prop. Replace `link` with `path` prop.

```js
<Router>
    <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Navi user={this.state.user} />} />
</Router>
```

Comment: @user12159191 why do you render Navi inside the router twice?

Comment: Thanks for your help. If you could explain 1 more thing: my Navi component is 5 links. In the current state, 2 of those should appear in the Navi component. In now in my root page, all 5 links appear and on a different page, the 2 that appear with current state appear. My understanding is that given the above + your correction, on the root 2 links should appear and on a different page no links should appear. Is this correct or I am missing something about how routing works?

Comment: Mario Nikolaus I missed your second comment, that answered my second question.   <Route exact path="/"  component = {Navi} user = {this.state.user}/> I wasn't aware you could do this. Thanks a lot for your help man.

Comment: @user12159191 no problem, glad I could help.